org-ref-insert-ref-link across multiple org files
I have a project with tens of *.org files, at various folder depth levels, which I intend to export as a single PDF file using Latex. When running org-ref-insert-ref-link I get a list of all labels in the current file. How can I tell org-mode to show instead all labels from all files in my project?
I would like to mimic what org-ref-insert-cite-link does in conjunction with something as follows:
[[bibliographystyle:unsrt]]
[[bibliography:
~/file1.bib,
~/file2.bib]]

With the above I have access to all bibliography entries within file1.bib, file2.bib, ...
Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

I don't know the code well, but a quick look suggests that the best place to modify is org-ref-select-label: it currently uses org-ref-get-labels to generate the completion list and a comment in that provides an explanation for why it limits itself to the current file: It is important for this function to be fast, since we use it in font-lock.  There is no such admonition for org-ref-select-label however, so it could look all over the place for labels and add them to the list. But you'd have to write the function that does that.
